# Pandas: Compare an column with values of an list and copy matching rows

Tags: python, pandas

I`am looking desperate for help .. somehow I got list in a seemingly easy task.

I have a list with values:

`quotes = ['1234','34523','34234','34242',...]`

And a dataframe:

| index | quote | business_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1234 | Cloud |
| 1 | 6623 | Cloud |
| 2 | 1234 | Cloud |
| ... | ... | ... |

Now I want to copy **just** the quotes which are in my list `quotes` and create a new dataframe with all columns of the given `df`

For that I already tried to use is_in:

```
dict_unique_quote_id = {'quotes':[quotes]}

q = df.isin(dict_unique_quote_id).all(1)
print(q)
```

But then I get a bunch of `False` values. I checked it manually the values in `quotes` are existing in `df`.

I think I am getting something fundamentally wrong .. thanks for your help!!

Comment: You need `df[df.quote.isin(quotes)]` ?

Comment: Or `df[df.quote.astype(str).isin(quotes)]` ?

Comment: Oh man .. thank you!!